# How to represent plain text as html text in jsp?

Tags: html, jsp, struts

I am using struts 1.3 to develop application. I have requirement where i need to represent the property value as html text. I have a property called commentText which is of type string and i am printing the property value by using `<bean:write>`

```
<td width="8%"><span class="formlabel">
    <bean:message key="ui.jsp.dashboard.news.showNews.button.message" />
</td>
<td width="80%">
  :&nbsp;&nbsp;<bean:write name="record" property="commentText" />
</td>
```

How to represent this plain text as html text ?

Any suggestions are welcome,

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If its an simple text of type string put in between  [span tag](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_span.asp)

```
   <span>:&nbsp;&nbsp;<bean:write name="record" property="commentText" /></span>.
```

And better to use the `JSTL`

```
<c:out value="YourNormalStringHere" escapeXml="false"/>
```

Comment: its not a simple string, in some cases it may have http links to other sources and i need to make this part of the text as hyperlink

Comment: See updated answer and also have a look on this http://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-0306.html.That is a util method to convert into html.If you are not willing to use JSTl

Comment: @Suresh, page not found. Is there any other link ? will be of great help

Comment: I tried using JSTL. My property has the value `Google: http://google.com` I need google.com to be hyperlinked as it is shown in the above comment made by you. the text has to display as it is only the link to be as hyperlink.

Comment: No,it should work,When you set escape to false.CHeck the String coming from DB is proper or not.http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wchelp/v5r6/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.commerce.developer.doc/refs/rsdjspbpescapexml.htm

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/26223/discussion-between-the-suresh-atta-and-srikanth-sridhar)